# Why I don't have 'Bind Sort Control' option in Crystal subreport?

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a report and two subreports. In the subreports I used Sort Record Expert for defining the column that I want to sort the subreport. I would like to have a sort control, but I don't have the option 'Bind Sort Control'.

Could someone be kind and explain me how to create the sort control in the subreport, if possible. Maybe I am missing something...

Thank you very much !

Comment: A Bind Sort Control kind of thing inside the report? Sorry, don't think there is such a thing.

Comment: The option when you right click one of the header fields of the subreports. There is no 'Bind Sort Control' or something like this for adding a control for sorting the records.

Comment: Is this an on-demand subreport (opens in new window)?

Answer (score 3):

"Bind Sort Control" was first released into the product in 2008 - version 12. 
My guess is that you are using an earlier version like Crystal Reports X1?
Note that Crystal Reports X1 is version 11, and not the same thing as Crystal Reports 2011 (version 14)

Answer (score 0):

As PowerUser says, I don't think you can do that in Crystal. The closest you could come would be to have a parameter to select sort item, but that would require re-running the report each time yu wanted to re-sort it.

Alternatively, the output could be exported to Excel and then manipulated in Excel. (However, Crystal's Excel export isn't very good.)

Comment: This might be a new feature as of 2008 - I don't recall seeing it in previous versions.